# AOLserver, apache2

Tags: apache2

I am using 3.13.0-77-generic #121-Ubuntu  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 for hosting two websites.

Issue i faced is:
apaches services went down and sites down. When i checked, i got this error in restarting apache services:

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

I checked all configuration and everything was perfect. I then checked AOLserver process were running.So i killed the process, and restarted apache services again.This is no the first time i faced this issue. It pops in all of a sudden, i had to kill AOLServer services to run apache2 services again.

My question is: What is AOLserver and what can i do to avoid such issues in future.

I could not find much information in logs about the server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AOL Server is America Online's Open-Source web server. AOLserver is the backbone of the largest and busiest production environments in the world. AOLserver is a multithreaded, Tcl-enabled web server used for large scale, dynamic web sites.

Apache is also a web server like AOL.
You could run both AOL and Apache2 using proxy module in apache2.

Also, Apache2 can be easily configured to work with AOL.

The fact is that AOL Server and Apache 2 Server are competing for port 8080

i suggest you run AOL on a separate port or uninstall it if you do not use it.

**To run AOL Server on port 8080**

Edit 
`/etc/aolserver4/aolserver4.tcl:`

```
array set debian_config {
    HOSTNAME localhost
    ADDRESS 127.0.0.1
    HTTP_PORT 8080
    HTTPS_PORT 443
}
```

then run to restart both servers 
`/etc/init.d/aolserver4 restart
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

then configure apache2 to use a proxy for requests by adding or editing an existing site in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`
For instance i edited `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.conf` and placed this code there

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    ProxyRequests Off 
    ServerName www.site1.com 
    ServerAlias site1.com 
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/site1/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/site1/
</VirtualHost>
```

After which you enable the **apache modules proxy & apache proxy_http** with commands

```
sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart
```

It means you have to manually direct requests to the AOL server from Apache2 via proxy, keeing both servers active.

Comment: Thankyou for explaining and providing suggestion. But i am still confused over some things, Like, why aol and apache compete for 8080, when standard port for apache is 80. Also, why everything suddenly.. Can you provide some good reference links about aol server?

Comment: all services on your server run on ports. the web server well known port is 80. that is why both apache2 and AOL define the server port. for the purpose of using both servers simultaneously, you must run one of them on a separate unused port. i suggest 8080, but some service on your server could be using 8080. you must choose a free port. your ubuntu server starts AOL and before Apache2 because of their names alphabetical names. details on AOL server (https://aolserver.github.io/)

Comment: @newbie port 80 being a standard port does not prevent the server from starting a different service on it. its first come, first served. once port is taken it is locked. until you stop the service using the port is when it is freed for another service to use it.  more info on AOL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOLserver)